# Android mapview bigger zoom

Tags: android, android-mapview

Is it possible to set bigger zoom than maximum zoom? I need to set bigger zoom to show custom layer, that has many detail in big zoom. It doesn't mather how would look google layer.
Or is it possible to disable google layer and set bigger zoom?